# Logout of RESTful Web API while sending the login authentication token as a cookie

Tags: vb.net, cookies, httpclient, restful-authentication

I have successfully built a log in function that provides the authentication token via json.  This is what i have so far for logging out.  the URL must be appended with the string "logout" and I must include a cookie with a value equal to the authentication token.  I have tried many other methods but I thought this was the closest I came.  I dont need any content but do I have to include something? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
Public Function LOGOUT(inURL As String, authToken As String)
    Dim inURI As New Uri(inURL + "logout")
    Dim cookieHolder As New CookieContainer
    Dim response As New HttpResponseMessage
    Using Handler As New HttpClientHandler() With {.CookieContainer = cookieHolder}
        cookieHolder.Add(inURI, New Cookie("authToken", authToken))
        Using client As New HttpClient()
            response = client.PostAsync(inURI, Nothing).Result
            If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                Dim json As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                'Form1.TextBox1.Text = client.DownloadString(address).ToString
                'Dim json As String = client.PostAsync(inURI, Nothing)
                'Dim InstanceURL As String
                'InstanceURL = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("response.URL").ToString
                'MsgBox(InstanceURL)
                'Return InstanceURL
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Since that was not working I tried another method

```
Public Function LOGOUT(inURL As String, authToken As String) As Boolean
    LOGOUT = False
    Dim inURI As New Uri(inURL + "logout")
    Dim client As New HttpClient
    Dim _cookieContainer As New CookieContainer()
    Dim myCookie As Cookie = New Cookie("authToken", authToken)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(inURI)
    Try
        _cookieContainer.Add(inURI, myCookie)
        request.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse() ''500 error
        MsgBox(response.ToString)
        LOGOUT = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        LOGOUT = False
    End Try
End Function
```

I am still getting the 500 error

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I am an idiot...LOL I forgot a lot of the request properties.

```
Public Function LOGOUT(inURL As String, authToken As String) As Boolean
    LOGOUT = False
    Dim inURI As New Uri(inURL + "logout")
    Dim client As New HttpClient
    Dim cookieContainer As New CookieContainer()
    Dim myCookie As Cookie = New Cookie("authToken", authToken)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(inURI)
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14"
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = False
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    request.Method = "POST"
    'request.ContentLength = authToken.Length
    Try
        cookieContainer.Add(inURI, myCookie)
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse() ''500 error
        If response.StatusCode = "200" Then
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbCrLf + "Logged Out " + response.StatusDescription
            'MsgBox(response.StatusDescription)
            LOGOUT = True
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        LOGOUT = False
    End Try
End Function
```